# Get distinct email subjects to trigger flow only for first message instead of all the messages

Tags: power-automate

I have a flow, which is based on incoming emails in a shared email. I have to add a particular condition and it does not work as I might not be implementing it correctly.

Trigger : When a new email arrives in shared mailbox (V2)
Frequency : 5 mnts

New condition: if same subject email arrives multiple times, then perform action ONLY once.

Possible approach: I was trying to put a array and do distinct using union and then do the desired action. This sounded correct but my implementation did not yield the desired result.

[image]

I have added screenshots from my flow. where I am going wrong? Any other ideas are appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is very difficult to achieve using your current trigger. You would have to track with very little latency what you have already processed.

How about you use a scheduled flow to run every few minutes, get all new messages and define rules to find duplicates and process only what is relevant?